# How to get filtered Data result set from jQuery Datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

It would be great if someone help me on the issue.

I am just trying to get the filtered result set from the Datatable.

Below is my code.

```
var filtered_row_data = $('#example').DataTable().column(1).search('186').data().unique().sort();

 console.log(JSON.stringify(filtered_row_data));
```

It just returns all the rows instead of filtered values.

I am using latest stable version of Datatable.

Can anyone please help on this?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

see dataTables [**selector-modifiers**](https://datatables.net/reference/type/selector-modifier). You are looking for `{filter : 'applied'}` :

```
table.on('search.dt', function() {
    //number of filtered rows
    console.log(table.rows( { filter : 'applied'} ).nodes().length);
    //filtered rows data as arrays
    console.log(table.rows( { filter : 'applied'} ).data());                                  
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/h4wrmfx3/**

Comment: its work but when i use it twice!, strange, when i hit search button and console it, its show me 10 record but when i hit search again its show me 3 (which is correct no). can you please help to fix this?

Comment: @Rohit, can you reproduce this in a fiddle? Tried the answers fiddle above, it seems to work as expected.

Comment: as per your suggestion this is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/RohitSavaliya2010/sz7w5uvr/1/ can you please check it?

Comment: @Rohit, well, it does not work, just some code out of context :) You can grab the above http://jsfiddle.net/h4wrmfx3/  and add / modify then update or fork.

Comment: because of not including ajax file its not work in js fiddle , rather then my code is work perfect & search is also work good but when i console              console.log(srch_table.rows( { filter : 'applied'} ).nodes().length); 
is first show me 10 record which is default paging and when i hit search button second time its return me correct value of search count. hope u understand.

Comment: @Rohit, but you have no search, you have actually turned filtering off. What you do is that you reload the entire dataset.  You'll never a "applied" value which differs from total number of rows.

Comment: @davidkonrad can I ask you, i was searching this for hours i was looking this documentation (https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows()) but i couldnt find any other docs that specify this, i was wondering where i can find this extra details :)

Comment: @Manza follow the link to https://datatables.net/reference/type/selector-modifier (the same as in the answer)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using server side filtering / searching, this is the only solution i found and it works: [xhr event](https://datatables.net/reference/event/xhr)

```
$('#yourTable').on('xhr.dt', function ( e, settings, json, xhr ) {
        //the new data is here json.data
        console.log(json.data);
});
```